# Include a file if it exists

Tags: xcode

Is it possible? I have my file with custom debug predefines, and I want to include it on my side but skip on repository side (without differences in XCode project file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot conditionally include a file based in its existence so the best thing to do would be to include an empty file on the repository side and attempt to avoid it being added when you add content to it on 'your' side.  Sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.  Why are these defines so private?

Answer (score 0):

**To your direct question**: No. XCode does not have conditional file inclusion.

**To your intent**: You would be better off making a separate build configuration. Each build configuration (Debug, Release, Distribution, etc.) contains a separate set of compiler settings, and optionally a set of user-specified definitions.

See [Fine-Tune Your Builds](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Building/Building.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH9-SW24) in the [XCode 4 User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215).